# Can you install a custom SSIS component in a location other than the GAC?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Can I install a custom SSIS component into another location besides the GAC?  I need to deploy the custom SSIS component to the SSIS server, but I may not be able to have access to the GAC on that server.  I am wondering if there was another way besides installing to the GAC?  I know there is a way when using 3rd party DLL's with a Script Task or Script Component, but wasn't sure if there was a way with SSIS custom components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can [manually load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbrowne/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac) the dll using reflection

Please see below example, you can add these two methods to your script task.

```c#
static ScriptMain()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
}

static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.Contains("BouncyCastle.Crypto"))
    {
        string path = "C:\\SO\\bouncycastle\\";
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"));
    }
    return null;
}
```

[image: DLL location]

You also would still need to reference the dll within the script task

[image: Reference the dll]

Comment: thanks for the reply!  This works if I am using a 3rd party DLL when using a Script Task or Script Component.  I am not using a Script Task or Script Component, I have create a custom SSIS Data Flow component that I can drag and drop from the SSIS Toolbox into a package.  When it is used in a package it needs to be install in the GAC, but I don't have access and was looking to see if there was another way without using the GAC.